# Gmaps4Rails build_markers not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, gmaps4rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to build a markers Json with build_markers. It seems to build the hash right when I display it in the page but somehow in javascript it returns null.

javascript (not using require tree if that matters)

```
function initialize() {

handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom:17, minZoom:5}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

   handler.fitMapToBounds();
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

controller

```
      def index
    @apartments = Apartment.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@apartments) do |apartment, marker|
      marker.lat apartment.latitude
      marker.lng apartment.longitude
    end
  end
```

When checking source it just shows handler.addMarkers(null)

Comment: No idea, try with `@hash = @apartments.map {|a| {lat: a.latitude, lng: a.longitude } } `

Comment: that has to be something javascript related, because I can print out the values in the DOM without problem. It's javascript that's interpreting them as null

Comment: I cant see any reason, sorry

Comment: @Kkulikovskis Did you ever figure out the problem? I'm having the same issue right now and it is very frustrating. My experience is the exact same as yours

Comment: @szier no, sorry. But if this problem is not answered anywhere yet I will take another look.

Comment: @szier actually... if I remember correctly my javascript was in a js file not inline. Might be the case that it evaluates javascript files before ruby evaluation. Try putting the javascript inline (inside the view) and see if the problem persists... waiting for feedback